# Null entity value

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, view, model, entity

My `User` model:

```
    public class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public int RoleId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required, DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required, DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public Role Roles { get; set; }
}
```

My `Roles` model:

```
public class Role
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

But in the view the name of the `Role` is empty... what should I do or where is the problem the database relations or anywhere else?

```
<dt>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Roles.Name)
</dt>

<dd>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Roles.Name)
</dd>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve that problem using [eager loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#eager) to load the related entity as part of your query, eg:

```
var query= context.Users.Include(u=>u.Role).Where(...).ToList();
```

In the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#eager) I quote above you'll find all the options you have to load related entities.

Just a FYI, your entities don't meet all the conditions that need lazy loading to create proxy classes from your entities, you can see all the conditions in this other [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx). You need to declare your navigation properties as `virtual` to be lazy loaded, but I recommend you use eager loading in this case. At the time  you consult a navigation property in your view, you DbContext will be disposed, so an exception will be thrown.

### Update

Well you can create an overload of your `GetAll` method where you pass as parameter the related entities you want to load:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
//...
public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll(List<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>> includes = null) 
{

  IQueryable<TEntity> query = _dbSet; 

  if (includes != null)
  {
     query = includes.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));
  }
  return query;
}
```

Comment: Hi octavioccl, I couldn't use the Include in my query because I'm using a DAL, for example I made a constructor to access the information from the db in my instance BaseRepository<User> users, I call the method GetAll(); but when i'm trying to Include the option doesn't appear

Comment: It is IQueryable<T> this is my method    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            return dbSet;
        }
And in my controller my instance is IBaseRepository<User> users; idk if i'm loading well the relation tell me if i'm wrong, users.GetAll() <- i guess in here is where the include goes, right?

Comment: using System.Data.Entity; yeap, my mistake.